# How to Read System Message With a Discord Bot (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have developed a discord bot that does many things on the server. Recently I decided to automate a simple task. Whenever someone boosts my server, a system message is sent to one of the channels - "ABC just boosted the server!"
I am trying to read this message to fetch the ID so I can make my bot thank the user for boosting. But I am unable to read the message as message.content is coming as blank. I believe that is because it is a system message and not sent by any user. Can anyone help me with this? How do I get the id of the booster?

Here's the code block.

```
var channalPosting = "848630009056067596"; // 
client.channels.cache.get(channalPosting).send("NitroBoost : " +message.content);
```

the value is coming as  -

```
(NitroBoost : )
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could simply check for the booster role of the member using the guildmemberupdate event

```
<client>.on('guildMemberUpdate', async (oldMember, newMember) => {
  const prevRole = oldMember.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Nitro Booster');
  const currentRole = newMember.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Nitro Booster');

  if (!prevRole && currentRole) {
    newMember.guild.channels.get(yourchannelid).send('someone boosted pogU');
  }
});
```

replace client with your Discord.Client() variable and replace yourchannelid with the actual channel id

Comment: Thank u so much for replying. I will try it now..but seems like it won't work if a person having booster role boosts again, right?

Comment: @PrabhatRayal yeah thats an issue